# Как errors.Wrap() влияет на логирование ошибок?

Tags: golang, логирование, обработка-ошибок

Что дает `errors.Wrap(err, "Text")` в go? Предположим, я получил ошибку из бд, обернул ее, вернул обертку в бизнес логику, там еще раз обернул, вернул в обработчик и там хочу залогировать. Как эти обертки помогут мне с логом?

Comment: Не затрутднит Вас дать ссылку на API `errors.Wrap`? В стандартном модуле [errors](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/) такого метода нет.

Comment: главное не вернуть по API. так как в ошибках могут быть скрытие детализации. а на логируете как `%+v` , то в лог попадет весть стек ошибок которые вы обернули по очереди

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о методе [этого модуля](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#Wrap), то `errors.Wrap()` позволяет добавить свой контекст (своё сообщение) в эту ошибку. В бизнес-логике или выше по стеку вы можете достать все добавленные сообщения или залогировать stacktrace ошибки, начиная с вашего верхнего уровня (см. [пример](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#example-package-StackTrace)), что вам поможет более быстро разобраться с ней.

В принципе, цель этого пакета заключается вот в этом предложении:

> The errors package allows programmers to add context to the failure
> path in their code in a way that does not destroy the original value
> of the error.